# Blocking pop-up ads or any other ads from popping out in iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to block pop-ads by using:

```
<div class="iframe">
   <iframe sandbox = "allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/testing" ></iframe>
</div>
```

It used to work but now they detect it and they will disable their videos from playing and in console it will throw an error:

> Blocked opening 'URL' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.

Is there any other way to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

I think using the sandbox attribute can help you.

```html
<ifame src="#" sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

This will help you running javascript but block all kind of dialog boxes

Comment: Hey there, still almost the same it throws an error 
Blocked opening 'https://website.com' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.

Comment: Then you can further add allow-forms in the sandbox attribute, it will not block form submissions or page requests

Comment: sadly bro same thing happened this time the player just keeps loading

Comment: I mean, it's a 10 second search https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/sandbox#allow-popups